# C++ string to char conversion

Tags: c++, c, rogue-wave

I have a function which requires parameter to be of type 'unsigned char'.

If I use:

```
unsigned char x[8] = "a\0ab-cd";
```

and pass this 'x' as parameter to the function call, I get the desired result.

However, I get inputs as RWCStrings, and not char type variable.

In my case, I have :

```
RWCString a1 = "a";
RWCString b1 = "ab-cd";
```

I try to concatenate this using :

```
RWCString final = a1 + "\0" + b1;
```

and then try using conversion inside function call as 
(unsigned char*) final.data();

However, this produces a different result for the called function.

What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: `RWCString` is not a standard C or C++ data type. If you are using some special library or framework, please add relevant details to your questions.

Comment: @paulsm4, `RWCString`s are not regular C strings, and so OP's use of `=` and `+` are fine as overloaded operators have been provided. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19422-01/819-3702/CSt_8054.htm#Assignment Operators

Comment: Try removing the extra `+"\0"` in the middle of the assignment of `final`. The documentation notes that the null character is included as part of assignment.

Comment: My personal guess is that "\0" will be treated like an empty string. You probably need to inject a null character differently. For example, if you'd use `std::string s` you couldn't use `s + "\0"` to get a string with a null character but you could use `s.push_back(0)`.

Answer (score 2):

When doing the a1 + "\0" operation, SourcePro evaluates "\0" as an string with length = 0, thus just returning a1.

The documentation for the [+= operator](http://www.roguewave.com/portals/0/products/sourcepro/docs/12.5/html/sourceproref/classRWCString.html#a528adb5a72095d791010ca29981b7663) specifically notes that the operator doesn't support strings with embedded nulls.